# Draw a shape over existing view

Tags: android, view, drawing, android-canvas

I have a view and I want to draw a shape on it (circle for example) after click.
[image]

I've tried to do this but there are two problems -

1. onDraw is never called.
2. Not sure the setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams) will give me the result I want.

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           CircleView circle = new CircleView(GameXoActivity.this, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
           circle.setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
           circle.startDrawing();
       }
   ```

CircleView:

```
    public CircleView(Context context, int width, int height) {
        super(context);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    protected void startDrawing() {
        this.postInvalidate(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onDraw");
        // draw circle
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

The shape is not an image and I want to draw it with animation (I didn't write the entire code).
Also, the shape is not always a circle, so using a drawable-state is not an option. 
Because there is not just one view, but 9, I don't think the making 9 more on top of them would be right.

Comment: You should use a selector.

Comment: You should be using just `invalidate()`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein If you're answer was so right, then it could have helped others. So it's sad that you deleted it and down-voted my question just because I didn't want to except your answer.

Comment: No, it wasn't. After all, it didn't answer your always changing specs.

Comment: There's only one way to draw a circle. You invented another one. Sorry I don't explain the obvious. Good luck to you.

Comment: @Abs, sorry; bad wording on my part. I meant, did you get your CircleView figured out?

Comment: @MikeM. Getting closer to the solution. The onDraw is called but it doesn't draw anything. I'll read more about canvas and figure it out.. I know there are different ways to solve this but I really want to do it with canvas because I've never done anything with canvas and I want learn how to use it. And also I think that's the best solution for what I'm trying to do.. Thanks!

Comment: @Abs, I agree, and, if I'm understanding your goal correctly, I think I've got a simple example that'll get you started. I can post it, if you'd like.

Comment: @MikeM. That would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you'll need to customize this quite a bit, I've left things rather generic. The following example will animate a blue circle being drawn clockwise, starting from the east (0 degrees), on top of the View's content when the View is clicked.

```
public class CircleView extends View
{
    private static final int MARGIN = 50;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    RectF rect = new RectF();

    boolean drawing = false;
    float sweep = 0;

    public CircleView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, sweep, false, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        rect.set(MARGIN, MARGIN, w - MARGIN, h - MARGIN);
    }

    public void startAnimation()
    {
        drawing = true;
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            sweep += 10;
            if (!(sweep > 360))
            {
                invalidate();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 20);
            }
            else
            {
                drawing = false;
                sweep = 0;
            }
        }   
    };
}
```

In this Activity example, I used an image that most developers would already have in their project, but it can obviously be changed to your custom image. Also, for the sake of simplicity and brevity, the CircleView is set as the entire content of the Activity, but it can easily be listed in an xml layout, as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    CircleView circle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        circle = new CircleView(this);
        circle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        circle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    circle.startAnimation();
                }
            }
        );      

        setContentView(circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mess with drawing of the object you should override`public void draw(Canvas canvas)` and not `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)`
EDIT:Please read comments, this first statement of my answer is probably wrong

but I would use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout and put the images one on top of another.
Then you can play with the visibility of the overlaying image in order to hide/show it.

EDIT:
In case your circle is not an image and needs to be drawn, make your own circle class extending View and use it as a component in the FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as you would do if it were an image

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. The `draw()` method is for rendering a View onto a Canvas passed to it. `onDraw()` is called when a View is rendering itself, and hands you the Canvas to alter as needed.

Comment: Mike M I did not actually tested it. thanks for correcting me.

Comment: It's not an image and I want to draw it with animation (I didn't write the entire code). That's why I'm using onDraw(). Because there is not just one view, but 9, I don't think the making 9 more on top of them would be right.

Comment: Then you can use the class AnimationDrawable and set it as a background to your overlayed view http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html
Then you have to start() for the animation to play.

Comment: I want to use canvas for this. I know the frame-animation way and if it had been a more detailed drawing I would have use it. but I can't see the point of using about 50 images for each shape I want to draw..

Comment: then if you definately need the canvas, find out why onDraw() is not running. On your code I cannot see CircleView extending View or be added in a Layout parent. This is probably why onDraw() is not running

Comment: I added the CircleView to the layout (in the xml) and now the onDraw is called, but still nothing is drawn. But i guess that's another question.. I'll soon look into to that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, create two imageView with same dimensions, set the image you want to display on image view and then make the second image invisible . 
For example :

```
circleimage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//now its hidden(do it OnCreate)
```

and then show 2ndimage when 1stimage is clicked(do it in onclick of 1st image)

```
circleimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It's not just a circle image, there are other shapes that can be drawn there. And I want to draw it with animation, so I can't use visibility.

Comment: but if u use frame Animation to your 2nd image it looks like drawing.[Frameanimation](http://www.edureka.co/blog/frame-animation-in-android/).